# Performace of a view: Pass collection to a function, applied to a column vs SELECT in the function

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

If I have

```
function(col) new_col
```

in a view, and I need a list (SELECT column FROM tbl), big and always the same, for this fuction, should I pass a collection

```
function(col, CAST(MULTISET(SELECT column_name1 FROM table_name) AS T_TEXT)) new_col
```

Or just make a select inside this function? Or are there any better solutions?

**Edit:** The result of the function is just a VARCHAR2, in fact, it's multiple_replace function and the input collection for this function is all the strings_to_replace. Those strings_to_replace are always the same for each view row and are selected from a table.

Comment: It might help if you gave some indication of what the result set with the existing function looks like and what you want it to look like with the new function.

Comment: There may be a theoretically best method of the two you propose, but since you have the code and the data and the methods available to you, it seems like you should be able to test the performance yourself, and then look for clarification on any unexpected results.